# Send id from view in AJAX call asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this data table :

```
<table id="files" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Thumbnail</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Number of downloads</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>File Type</th>
            <th>Published On</th>
            <th>Created On</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var file in Model.Files)
        {
            var thumbPath = "~/Thumbnails/" + file.ThumbnailPath;
        <tr>

            <td><img style="width:80px;height:80px;" src="@thumbPath" asp-append-version="true" /></td>
            <td><a asp-controller="files" asp-action="details" asp-route-id="@file.Id" class="text-dark">@file.Name</a></td>
            <td id="downloads">@file.DownloadCounter</td>
            <td>@file.Genre.GenreName</td>
            <td>@file.FileT.FileTypeName</td>
            <td>@file.PublishedOn</td>
            <td>@file.Year</td>
            <td>@file.Author</td>
            <td>
                <a asp-controller="files" asp-action="QrCode" asp-route-id="@file.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Qr Code</a>
                <a asp-controller="files" asp-action="EditFile" asp-route-id="@file.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td style="display:none;" id="fileId">@file.Id</td>
        </tr>
        
    }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

i want to sent file.Id for each file in Model.Files in this ajax call :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dateto').change(function () {
            var DateFrom = $('#datefrom').val();
            var DateTo = $('#dateto').val();
            var fileId = $('#fileId').val();
            
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "Home/NumberDownloads/?dateFrom=" + DateFrom + "&dateTo=" + DateTo + "&fileId= " +fileId,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }

                });
           
        });
    });
</script>
```

With this way it doesnt work fileId is always 0,everything else work but i need your help how to send fileId in the call for each file in Models.File.

Comment: You are duplication id's and that is not good, since an ID needs to be unique. If you have multiple elements with the same id like `fileId`, then `$('#fileId')` would only return the first element

Comment: Can you show pls where  "#datefrom'   '#datefrom'  from? You have 100s file.Id but not any dates

Comment: dates are not problem they are  from 2 datepickers up in this view but I don't post them because they work,but my function in backend needs id of a each file  in Models.File

Comment: You have to post everything , what you  have posted  doesn' t make any sense

Comment: you can understand me better if you see the answer...

Comment: but this is not smartest way to this filter because i will send too much requests to the server i will find other way,dont waste your time solving this,thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dateto').change(function () {
                var DateFrom = $('#datefrom').val();
                var DateTo = $('#dateto').val();
                var fileId = $('#fileId').html();
                
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "Home/NumberDownloads/?dateFrom=" + DateFrom + "&dateTo=" + DateTo + "&fileId= " + fileId,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#downloads').empty();
                        $('#downloads').append(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

With this I achieve what I want but only for first element in `Model.Files`.

I want to repeat this Ajax call for all elements in `Model.Files` or simple said call this Ajax foreach iteration of foreach loop.